# How to get timestamp in nanosecond (or anything close to that) in rust?

Tags: rust

I need to add a timestamp to the data i collect, the data is collect quite fast, so second and milisecond based timestamp can't do the job well. I'm looking into nanosecond timestamp so how to get timestamp in nanosecond in rust?

Edit:
I want a timestamp that is monotonic, and increase at a very fast rate, since the data collection is quite fast and every record need a timestamp.

Comment: You should precise what kind of timestamp you want. Programs dealing in nanoseconds don't usually like non monotonous time sources for example.

Comment: Edited question to include what kind of timestamp i want.

Comment: It's still unclear. Do you want something universally monotonic (which is impossible without a specific hardware) or only during the execution of your program ?

Comment: I want something universally monotonic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such direct function but you can get the number of nanoseconds elapsed since Unix Epoch with `SystemTime` and `Duration`:

```rust
use std::time::{Duration, SystemTime};
let duration_since_epoch = SystemTime::now().duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap();
let timestamp_nanos = duration_since_epoch.as_nanos(); // u128
```

If you need nanoseconds, you probably don't need them as an absolute timestamp though. It's probable you don't want a timestamp but a duration compared to an [`Instant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Instant.html).

Comment: The reason i avoid SystemTime is because `Distinct from the Instant type, this time measurement is not monotonic. This means that you can save a file to the file system, then save another file to the file system, and the second file has a SystemTime measurement earlier than the first. In other words, an operation that happens after another operation in real time may have an earlier SystemTime!`

Comment: @WilliamTaylor This is how time measurement work: the clock can be modified by the system's user. If you need something monotonic, then you use an instant, which isn't tied to the system's time but is monotonic during the execution of your program.

Answer (score 1):

The time standard library has support for nanoseconds: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html